# The "Summer 2010 Moderator Appointments" blog article is missing the appointees

Tags: bug, moderators, blog

On the blog from the [11th of July 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/11/summer-2010-moderator-appointments/) it is announced which new moderators are appointed. For Stack Overflow this must have listed [Michael Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/michael-myers) because the [/users/moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) page links to the blog:

[image: user card of MMyers showing a link appointed 7/11/2010]

Something must gone missing in one of the many migrations of the blog content because it no longer mentions any of the appointed moderators. Not only is Michael not present but all other names disappeared as well. It looks like the table with the flairs in it didn't survive, based on the [Internet Archive copy of the orginal blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20100714135454/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/summer-2010-moderator-appointments/). The table and flairs certainly didn't make it into the [Jekyll version of that page](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/blob/master/_posts/2010-07-11-summer-2010-moderator-appointments.markdown).

[image: screenshot showing the blank spaces where the images should be]

Can this be restored in its original glory? If you prefer to not restore that content, can you unlink the text on the /moderators page for the affected moderator? There is a precedent for not having a link as Tim Post's appointment was also unlinked before he stepped down.

Comment: Well, the original blog post has iframe with HTML version of the flairs, which doesn't exist for long time. They'll have to copy the HTML from the Internet Archive, and design will be terrible unless they also copy CSS of the past blog.... all in all, big headache.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I saw iframe juggling that but I thought that was due to the Internet Archive trying to incorporate images while having the images archived as well.

Comment: No, the archive doesn't add iframes, I'm sure that's the original code in there.

Comment: This was an issue when the import to Jekyll ran. As Shadow mentions, the original blog post did use iframes for the flair, which wasn't supported by the importer used with Jekyll and it just deleted the element altogether. See 67 and 100 in the [commit history for the Jekyll blog](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/899a8b32a8582cc225d2ced5eaa940c60cf30849#diff-d226354eab7ab3d05ffbc662bfa585ce7939987f5e033a4e95b631ad9956ee6b) which switched from HTML files to Markdown.

Comment: Would it be too much work to manually edit that blogpost to include those 4 flairs? @animuson. I figure that would be a quicker task then manually changing the URL's on the elected dates of moderators.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not sure if that is true. At least one of the users that became mod then left the SE network by clicking on *delete account* so no flair there. It Won't be that easy ....

Comment: @rene, then use the archived version of the flair, as the internet archive obviously has it ;)